# Looking for a simple algorithm to scale/resize a matrix, or an image.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, interpolation, image-processing

I am looking for a simple algorithm to scale a matrix of any size.

Given matrix A of dimensions [w1,h1].

Given a scaling factor (or resizing factor) SF, which is a real number (not necessarily integer).

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the scaled (resized) matrix B.

The dimensions of matrix B will be [w1 x SF , h1 x SF], or to be more exact [round(w1 x SF) , round(h1 x SF)]

I heard that [Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is the best for this case, but I am not sure how easy it is to implement.

If possible, I will be happy to see the algorithm in a programming code (any language), or pseudo code.

Comment: I remember seeing some algorithm in Steven J Leon's Linear Algebra book. Sorry don't have the chapter, but maybe the index would help.

Comment: There wiki page you linked tells you how to do it. Is there something specific that's not clear?

Comment: The wiki page is very clear, but I was worried about corner cases, such as points in the boundaries.